# Probability; Coin toss. Discrete Math.

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

I flip a fair coin, independently, 10 times, resulting in a sequence of heads (H) and tails (T).
For each HT in this sequence, you win $3. Define the random variable X to be the amount
of dollars that you win. For example, if the sequence is
HHT T HT T HT T,
then X = 9. What is the expected value of X?

(a) 27/4

(b) 28/4

(c) 29/4

(d) 30/4

I thought it was HT HT H so 3+3+1.5 = 7.5

I do not know how to really solve this problem can someone explain why it is A?

Thanks!

Comment: Define $Y$ to be the number of times HT occurs in a sequence of 10 coinflips. Thus, $Y \in \{0,1,\ldots,5\}$. Can you find $\mathbb{P}(Y = k), ~ k = 0,1,\ldots,5$? The amount of dollars that you win $X = 3Y$, so that $\mathbb{E}[X] = 3\mathbb{E}[Y] = 3 \sum_{k = 1}^5 k \mathbb{P}(Y = k)$. The only difficulty is to find $\mathbb{P}(Y = k)$. Hope this hint helps.

Answer (score 1):

Since each toss is independent, $\mathbb{P}(\text{"HT occurs"})=\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{4}$. In 10 tosses there are 9 consecutive pairs in which you can the sequence HT with probability $\frac{1}{4}$ (and any other sequence with probability $\frac{3}{4}$). Hence,
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}(X)= 9\times\frac{1}{4}\times3$ + 9\times\frac{3}{4}\times0$=\frac{27}{4}$
\end{equation}